# Show distinct vectors of a vector space is basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $u$ and $v$ be distinct vectors of a vector space $V$. Show that if $\{u, v\}$ is a basis for $V$ and $a$ and $b$ are nonzero scalars, then both $\{u+v, au\}$ and $\{au, bv\}$ are also basis for $V$.

Comment: Do you know what a basis is ? Then, what do you need to prove about $\{u+v,au\}$ and $\{au,bv\}$ ?

Comment: Hi! Please share your thoughts and/ or your work

Comment: Show some of your own work/thoughts please

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{u,v\}$ is a basis, we know that we can write every $x\in V$ as
$$
x = x_1 u + x_2 v
$$
for unique scalars $x_1,x_2$.

I will show the first example $\{u+v,au\}$ the second example is not very different. Again take an arbitrary $x\in V$ then
$$
x = x_1 u + x_2 v = x_2u + x_2v + (x_1-x_2)u = x_2 (u+v) + \frac{(x_1-x_2)}{a}au.
$$
so every $x$ is in the linear span of $\{u+v,au\}$. Since $\{u+v,au\}$ has two elements and $V$ is two dimensional this set is also a basis.

Answer (score 1):

A basis for an n-dimensional space has three properties- and any two of them imply the third:
1) The set of vectors spans the space
2) The vectors in the set are independent.
3) The number of vectors in the set is n.

Here, we are told that {u, v} is a basis so we know all 3 of those.  In particular, we know (2)- that u and v are independent so if au+ bv= 0, we must have a=0 and b= 0 and (3) this vector space has dimension 2.

Then suppose, for some scalars, p and q, p(u+ v)+ q(av)= pu+ (p+ qa)v= 0.  Since u and v are independent, p= 0 and (p+ qa)= qa= 0.  Since a is non-zero, q= 0.  So u+ v and av are independent and there are 2 of them- they form a basis.

Suppose, for some scalarts, p and q, p(au)+ q(bv)= (pa)u+ (qb)v= 0.  Since u and v are independent, pa= 0 and qb= 0.  Since a and b are non-zero, p= 0 and q= 0.  So au and bv are independent and there are two of them- they form a basis.